# p:remoteCommand does not invoke the declared action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

Web page :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="../../Template/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form>

                <h:outputText id="montest" value="#{ProviderLogin.i}"/>

                <button class="ZWButtonActionIntervention pfButtonWhite" type="button" onclick="testpageRC()"/>
                    <span>TESTING</span>
                </button>

                <p:remoteCommand name="testpageRC" process="@this" update="montest" action="#{ProviderLogin.TESTING()}"/>

                <p:commandButton styleClass="ZWButtonActionIntervention pfButtonOrange" value="#{GestionIntervention.m_typeNonTraitee}" action="#{ProviderLogin.TESTING()}"/>

            </h:form>

        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

My java class (Bean)

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="ProviderLogin")
public class ProviderLogin implements Serializable
{ 
    private int i;

    public int getI(){return i;}

    public void TESTING(){i++;}
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the function 'TESTING()'

When I press the 'p:commandButton', the breakpoint is reached

When I press the 'button' (`p:remoteCommand` is called), the breakpoint is NOT reached

What is really strange, is that the 'p:remoteCommand' works for this: `update="montest"`
But, the method in the bean is not fired.

By the way, when I start to write `#{...` I have access to my bean (variable and methods)

I use Primefaces 6.2

Comment: `<button>` shouldn't be parts of primefaces. try `<p:button>` instead

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I tried, but a p:button is firing when page is loaded (the onclick). That's why i go for a RemoteCommand to call the bean method. I use a simple button element because i need some specific customization

Comment: At the moment, the problem is more "why my bean method is not call into the p:remoteCommand" since the "update" attribute works, why the action attribute doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found.

Every web pages defines the content of a template.
In this template there is the section "content" that cointained 2 `<h:form>`.
One is renderer when the user is not logged.
The other one is rendered when the user is logged correctly.

In each page that re-define the content (when user is logged), i had a second section of `<h:form>`. It seems that `action` of the `<p:remoteCommand>` doesn't manage this well while `<p:button>` does. I just deleted that form on each pages and my problem was solved.

My template (content part)

```
<div id="content" style="padding: 10px">
    <h:form rendered="#{!ProviderLogin.m_User.m_bLogged}">
        <h:button value="Connexion" outcome="/Gestion/Connexion.xhtml"/>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="formContent" rendered="#{ProviderLogin.m_User.m_bLogged}">
        <ui:insert name="content" >
            <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

One page that re-define the content part (with 2nd form that gave me errors)

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../Template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="formInterventions">
                PAGE CONTENT
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

The same page that re-define the content part (without 2nd form)
then, my `action` of the `<p:remoteCommand>` works !

```
 <h:body>
     <ui:composition template="../Template/template.xhtml">
         <ui:define name="content">
             PAGE CONTENT
         </ui:define>   
     </ui:composition>
 </h:body>
```

I also give you this informations :

i use `update` of some controls like this showcase :

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

You need to give the `id` of the control you want to `update`

When you are using `<h:form>`, sometimes you need to also specify the `id` of the `form` like this :

```
update="formID:controlID"
```

Because of that `<h:form>` defined in my template (which i forgot), it wasn't working because i didn't expect that at all and i didn't give that form an ID, so basically, a default id (j_idt27) was given.

This means my `update` functionnality couldn't find the specified control id

Comment: Next time post a [mcve] based on instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info, we're able to point out that sort of template-based mistakes in a minute then or probably you would already have figured out that all by youself ;)

Comment: @BalusC is this better ? :)

Comment: I mean, in the original question :) Your question wasn't a [mcve] at all, nobody had a clue how the file behind `<ui:composition template="../../Template/template.xhtml">` looks like, so it wasn't answerable for a long time. Moreover, the https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info link clearly explains to get rid of templates as much as possible and simply put everything in a single file.